# Problems wirh function composition in Haskell

Tags: haskell, io, function-composition

So... I have written this to get 5 rectangles from user :

```
rectangles <- sequence . take 5 . cycle [getRect]
```

But it doesn't work. Then I have refactored it as this which is shorthand for writing braces:

```
rectangles <- sequence $ take 5 $ cycle [getRect]
```

I'm not sure why my function compostion is not valid. I would expect it to work like this if I'm to translate it to "real world" function, no? :

```
sequence(take(5 , cycle(getRect)))
```

**[EDIT]**

I understand that (.) is for function composition and $ for application but my composition should return function and than apply [getRect] to it. Should it not?

I'm looking at this from purely mathematical standpoint. Let's say that

```
cycle : a -> b
take 5 : b -> c  -- partially applied
sequence : c -> d
```

So why doesn't my composition work? It should be a function with argument [getRect] like this :

```
(sequence . take 5 . cycle)([getRect]) : a -> d
```

Where `a` is [getRect] and `d` is result of IO action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function application binds more tightly than `(.)` so

```
sequence . take 5 . cycle [getRect]
```

is the same as

```
sequence . take 5 . (cycle [getRect])
```

since `cycle [getRect]` is list and not a function you get the error.

You can use parentheses to get the precedence you want:

```
rectangles <- (sequence . take 5 . cycle) [getRect]
```

note you could use `replicateM` instead:

```
rectangles <- replicateM 5 getRect
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood me. Can you take a look at my question again? I didn't use (.) after cycle, I have put space to apply `[getRect]` to my composed function.

Comment: Now I have noticed I should probably wrap `take 5` in braces because it's supposed to return partially applied function and this way it takes `(.)` as second argument, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Reygoch - Function application binds more tightly than `(.)` so `take 5 . cycle [getRect]` is `take 5 . (cycle [getRect])`